# Can we merge multiple FBX files, using Maya, and export as a single FBX file?

Tags: unity, maya, fbx, export

I have a humanoid model which is made up of four FBX files; one is for the human, one is for the T-shirt, one is for the pants and one is for the hair. I want to merge them into one FBX, because the manner in which I am using it requires using a single FBX file to represent the character.

Can we merge four FBX files into one, using Maya, and export as a single FBX file?

Comment: I have created a model library for talking where I have to take model in one fbx form , actually I don't know much about maya , thats why i asked is there any way to merge fbx file as one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merging multiple FBX files is actually fairly easy.

1. You first need to bring all of the FBX files into Maya. As I have found out, this is fairly simple. Just open an empty scene, and drag and drop the files from a file explorer.
2. Position all of the objects in Maya. If you are unfamiliar with Maya, itself, the basic transformation principles actually work very similar to Unity. After clicking on a model, for example, you can use <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the gizmo tools for moving, rotating and scaling, respectively.
3. Once you have all of your pieces in the desired positions, select *"Mesh > Combine"*.
4. Export the file with *"File > Export All"*, and be sure to select the FBX file type before you save.

That's it. Note that the object will still appear as a hierarchy of objects, when loaded into Unity, but they are all compressed into a single FBX file.

[image: I merge two cube models in Autodesk Maya 2015.]

Comment: Thank you so much you solved my problem.It works fine. But I have one more doubt how to provide the texture to the model

Comment: @ManishaMalik, thats outside my knowledge and current purview. You may ask a new question to find that out, if you can not find a solution.

Comment: @ManishaMalik That's all UV unwrapping. You probably want to leave the individual models as *submeshes* rather than outright combining them. That lets you use different materials for each submesh, but still keep them as "one" object.